# How to limit the length column in sql server reporting services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table and some of the cells contain a lot of data. I want to truncate it after 10 characters. In the design view I right clicked the column and clicked the text box properties where I unchecked allow height increase. I checked the preview and it fixed my problem, however after I deployed the report to reporting server the length of the column is increased again. Please help.

Comment: Why not just truncate it in your query using LEFT?

Comment: But later on I want to separate those by length so if len(name) <= 6 Display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three methods you could use:

**SQL Query**

In your SQL query, you could truncate the column like so:

```
SELECT LEFT(Foo,10)
```

**Calculated Field**

In the dataset, you could truncate the field into a new column using the expression:

```
=LEFT(Fields!Foo, 10)
```

**TextBox Field**

The same method applies as above but just in the textbox:

```
=LEFT(Fields!Foo, 10)
```